# How do i fix the file size limit ecxeeded message that display

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to recover jpg file in a memory card. 49 out of 50 display as expected but the last one display invalid or unsupported file format also an error message "file size limit exceeded" is displayed. can someone kindly tell me why this is. code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])

{

  if (argc != 2)

  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./recover image\n");
    return (1);
  }

  FILE * fileptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (fileptr == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open image file\n");
    return (2);
  }

  unsigned char array[512] = {0};
  int value = 0;
  char filename[8] = "";

  do {
    value = fread(array, sizeof(array), 1, fileptr);

  } while (!(array[0] == 0xff && array[1] == 0xd8 && array[2] == 0xff &&
      (array[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0));

  int count = 0;
  sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", count);
  FILE * img = fopen(filename, "w");

  while (value == 1) {
    do {
      fwrite(array, sizeof(array), 1, img);
      value = fread(array, sizeof(array), 1, fileptr);

    } while (!(array[0] == 0xff && array[1] == 0xd8 && array[2] ==
        0xff && (array[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0));

    count = count + 1;
    fclose(img);
    sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", count);
    img = fopen(filename, "w");
  }

  fclose(img);
  fclose(fileptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please google "file size limit exceeded". Also tell us what your platform is. The probable is because the jpg file you're trying to read is corrupt. Also use your debugger.

Comment: Why tag cs50???

Comment: because its a pset question from there

Comment: well, that explains why you're not just using photorec.

Comment: Note also that you're opening the file in **text** mode:  `FILE * fileptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");`  You can get away with that on POSIX systems that don't translate text file contents, but on systems that do, such as Windows, that will wreak havoc on binary files.  You need to open it in binary mode:  `FILE * fileptr = fopen(argv[1], "rb");`

Answer (score 3):

```
while( !(array[0] == 0xff && array[1] == 0xd8 && array[2] == 
               0xff && (array[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0));
```

Code is wrong. You don't copy until you find an aligned header. You copy the number of bytes the header says. Given you're trying to recover, you should extract at every valid header even if it overlaps another image.

Answer (score 3):

You are considering that a jpg ends just before the begining of the next jpg found. If you're lucky, all files will be consecutive, and all files will be jpg, and that's the reason all but the last one work.  The last one, obviously doesn't have a next jpg file, and therefore will fail.